# I have an issue with onClick methods for ListView items

Tags: android

I have an application which shows a list view. I am planning to make it so that when a user clicks on a listview item, a dialogue box appears showing an XML layout. But I am having just on little problem.

I have the list view up and running, and working. Here is the code in the activity class for the onclick listener.

```
 final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(VanillaBlockList.this, "Loading details for: " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(obj_itemDetails.getPrice().equals("ID - 1")){

                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.va_type1);
                    dialog.setTitle("Information");

                    dialog.show();

                }

                if(obj_itemDetails.getPrice().equals("ID - 2")){
              /* Stuff here*/ }
            } 

        });
    }
```

The problem is this part of the above code:

```
if(obj_itemDetails.getPrice().equals("ID - 1")){

                    // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.va_type1);
                    dialog.setTitle("Stone");

                    dialog.show();

                }
```

The line that creates the new dialog is giving me an error. In Eclipse, the "new Dialog(Context)" has the "Context" part underlined in red, indicating an error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you tell us what the error is, instead of just where it is?

I haven't worked much with Context or Dialog besides the very basics, but try passing in a Context object, not just the class.  In the onActivityCreate method, call

```
Context c = this;
```

and then

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass objects to Methods / Constructors. "Context" isn't an object.
Instead of new Dialog(Context) try getApplicationContext() or getActivityContext():

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: got it from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: Ah, on the link from D-32 on the developers reference, it uses mContext. I will try that also

Comment: I think you should look at the princeples of OO-Programming ;)
mContext is probably undefined, you have to insert "Context mContext = getApplicationContext();" above, or simpler, just do it like I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Context); May be problem is using Context.You use your activity name.this or getApplicationContext().